# Converting ASCII decimal

Tags: swift, postgresql, ascii

I receive two equivalent strings from my database depending on whether I ask for it in binary or text format.

Binary is hexadecimal... `4d4d002a0000100801010101010101...`(134916 characters)

Text is (I think ASCII decimal)... `//x3464346430303261303030...` (269832 characters)

I can convert the hexadecimal version into a byte array and ultimately an **NSData** (67458 bytes):

```
let data = NSMutableData(capacity: self.characters.count / 2)
for var index = self.startIndex; index < self.endIndex; index = index.advancedBy(2) {
    let byteString = self.substringWithRange(Range<String.Index>(start: index, end: index.advancedBy(2)))
    let byteUInt = UInt8(strtoul(byteString, nil, 16))
    data?.appendBytes([UInt8]([byteUInt]), length: 1)
}
```

But I am having no such luck with the text version. Tried parsing it a million different ways and I can't come up with an equivalent conversion.

If it matters, the database is PostgreSQL v9.5 and the data in text format is returned as a null-terminated character string (char *).

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that "ASCII representation" is a hex encoding of the hex encoding, so you should be able to produce a proper result by applying the same conversion twice:

```
34 | 64 | 34 | 64 | 30 | 30 | 32 | 61 | 30 | 30 | 30 | -- Original
 4 |  d |  4 |  d |  0 |  0 |  2 |  a |  0 |  0 |  0 | -- ASCII conversion
```